# Why do contrasts influence singular fits with mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, contrasts, parsimony

I've fit a linear mixed effects model to some data in R with `afex::mixed`. I'm interested in the fixed effect and have no expectations for the random effects structure; I just want the most parsimonious model specification.

My data consists of a numeric outcome `y`, a two-level categorical predictor `a` (`up` vs `down`), and participant IDs `p`. I want to know the fixed effect if `a` on `y`, while accounting for random effects by `p`.

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   1521 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ p: Factor w/ 100 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "Down","Up": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ y: num  12 0 13 0 0 10 5 0 0 5 ...
```

First I fit the maximally complex random effects structure:

```
> m1 <- mixed(y ~ a + (a|p), # maximal random effects structure
+             data = DF,
+             expand_re = TRUE, 
+             method = "S",
+             return = "merMod") 
Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: a, p
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
> summary(m1)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: y ~ a + (1 + re1.a1 | p)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 11625.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1982 -0.4479 -0.1815  0.2700  4.9898 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 p        (Intercept)  11.359   3.370       
          re1.a1        8.653   2.942   1.00
 Residual             112.938  10.627       
Number of obs: 1521, groups:  p, 100

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   6.8167     0.4414 106.1053   15.44   <2e-16 ***
a1            4.6929     0.4093 112.5658   11.46   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr)
a1 0.607 
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

It's singular. So I reduce the random effects structure by suppressing the correlation terms:

```
> m2 <- mixed(y ~ a + (a||p), # reduced complexity spec
+             data = DF,
+             expand_re = TRUE, 
+             method = "S",
+             return = "merMod") 
Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: a, p
> summary(m2)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: y ~ a + (1 + re1.a1 || p)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 11693.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0236 -0.5564 -0.1455  0.2483  5.0291 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 p        (Intercept)   7.726   2.78   
 p.1      re1.a1        4.841   2.20   
 Residual             118.777  10.90   
Number of obs: 1521, groups:  p, 100

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   6.8375     0.4039 100.1387   16.93   <2e-16 ***
a1            4.6081     0.3660  99.1904   12.59   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr)
a1 0.028
```

No more singular fit warning. Looks good. But I'd like treatment contrasts to more easily interpret the fixed effect:

```
> m2 <- mixed(y ~ a + (a||p), # reduced complexity spec
+             data = DF,
+             check_contrasts = FALSE, # use treatment contrasts
+             expand_re = TRUE, 
+             method = "S",
+             return = "merMod") 
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
> summary(m2)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: y ~ a + (1 + re1.aUp || p)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 11705.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8373 -0.6266 -0.1392  0.2322  5.0521 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 p        (Intercept)   6.561   2.561  
 p.1      re1.aUp       0.000   0.000  
 Residual             124.179  11.144  
Number of obs: 1521, groups:  p, 100

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   11.3858     0.4955  242.6631   22.98   <2e-16 ***
aUp           -9.1344     0.5842 1514.8102  -15.63   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr)
aUp -0.619
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Now the singular fit is back... What's happening here? Why does changing the contrasts determine whether the model is singular or not?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the output for the random effects estimates - is the random slope variance very small ? Have you tried extracting the random effects (slopes) ? Are they the same in both models ? I'm guessing not, so if the slopes are different then it is entirely plausible that the software could have difficulty estimating the variances.

Comment: @Robert Long -- I've edited the post to include model summaries and it looks like your intuition is correct: with treatment contrasts the variance among slopes is 0. Could you perhaps elaborate on why this is the case? And do you have any advice on how to interpret this in the context of model selection?